# How to use filters in mule requester module?

Tags: mule

I want request files with regex pattern in mule requester. Does anyone know how to do it?
https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-module-requester

I know how to request a single file but cant get it for regex filter.

My flow reads a file A_{todaysdatetime}.OUT and generates 3 different files through complex flow logic with each generated file name is in pattern *_{inputfilename}.

Anytime if error happens in flow, i want to move generated files from output to error directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Mule Requester Module you can set the resource to be a file endpoint like so:

```
<mulerequester:request config-ref="muleRequesterConfig" resource="myFileEndpoint" doc:name="Mule Requester"/>
```

Then, within the file endpoint that you've referenced, you can make use of regex filtering:

```
<file:endpoint name="myFileEndpoint" path="/" connector-ref="myFileConnector" doc:name="File"> 
    <file:filename-regex-filter pattern=" *** insert regex *** " caseSensitive="true"/>
</file:endpoint>
```

Hope that helps.